# Gboard: select current word, and compound words in German language

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, keyboard, swype, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using gboard from Google and I absolutely love it. I just have two questions about it because I come from using Swype which has a lot of nice and useful features to quickly  which i miss heavily:

1. Is it somehow possible to easily create compound words like it is in swipe? In the German language we often concanate words together. Right now, I have to insert two Words, and afterwards remove the space in between and change capitalisation. It's cumbersome
2. Is it possible to select a whole word using some shortcut on the keyboard? Currently, to change the capitalisation of a word or to remove some word, I need to select the whole word before pressing backspace or shift keys. But when I click into the word only the cursor is placed in between. So i always need to long press it and to select the whole word from the os context menu... it's cumbersome especially for the case of deleting a wrongly written word afterward.

Thanks a lot guys